# Redis key too long error for a key less than 512MB

Tags: redis, redis-py

I read that the redis key size limit is 512MB, but I'm running into `redis.exceptions.ResponseError: key too long` for a key much shorter than that (90k length). Does anyone know if this key size limit is configurable or why my key is considered too long? My redis version is 6.0.16.

For example, I tested with this file contents as the key:

`len=90000 ch='#'; printf '%*s' "$len" | tr ' ' "$ch" > test_key`

python code:

```
r = redis.Redis()
with open("test_key") as f:
    mykey = f.read()
r.set(mykey, 1)
```

`redis.exceptions.ResponseError: key too long`

Comment: Maybe you can try a binary search to establish the largest working key length? And maybe also see if the `redis-cli` is equally affected?

Comment: Works fine on redis 4.5.1 Python.

Comment: Btw, you can just use `mykey = '#' * 90_000`

Comment: I checked in the redis-cli and it has this same issue. Thanks for the tip about the key. I'm using redis 4.5.1 in python and my redis version is 6.0.16

Comment: It looks like the limit I'm running into is key sizes of can't exceed 65536 bytes.

Comment: Mmmm... that's an unsigned 16-bit size. Are you running on Windows? I used a 500MB key on Linux without issues.

Comment: My redis is running on an ubuntu image